# Post Form Data with updated div to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

> My view contains a Form like this:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Books

<form action="/Test/Run" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="getbooksbutton" value="Get Books From Person"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="books"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Data"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

> My Model:

```
public class Books
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<BooksDetails> BooksData { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class BooksDetails
{
    public string BookVersion { get; set; }
    public string BookPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I'm doing an ajax call to my Controller on getbooksbutton click with parameter "Title" and it returns and updates the div "books" with more details for the book by given name successfully.

> The div gets updated like this in my ajax function:

```
 var div = $("#books");
 $.each(data.BooksData, function(i, item) {
     div.append("<br/>" + "Book Version: " + item.BookVersion + ", Set your Price: " + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"item.BookPrice\" value=\"0\">");
 });
```

The user should be able to set a price for each book, thats why I'm appending an input field when the div gets updated.

When the user clicks the "final" submit button, I would like to post the Books Object to my controller with the updated BooksData object.

I had a look at many examples but I didn't found how that could work.

Comment: put your Person Object posting code.

Answer (score 0):

you must use model binding to a list you can change your code like this

```
  div.append("<br/>" + "Book Title: " + item.BookTitle + ", Set your Price: " + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"[i].BookPrice\" value=\"0\">");
```

for more information about this see [model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't answers. Please include the relevant details in your answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I add solution code to my answer.but I put link for a fast answer

Comment: Nobody's looking for fast answers, we want complete and correct answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is the way which you can use to solve your issue. This is not tested solution.

```
var Books = "";

$("#table tbody tr").each(function (index) {
    $("td", this).each(function () {
        if($(this).find('.books') != "" && $(this).find('.books')!=undefined)
        {
            var inputValues = [];
            $('#books input').each(function() {             
                inputValues.push($(this).val());                
            })
            Books = { "Title" : "Your title", "BooksData"  : inputValues };             
        }
    });
});
```

Now post this `Books` object to your controller using ajax call.